# remove html,head and body tags in php

Tags: php

I want to remove the html,head,boy tags from the html, Below is my html and the I want output without html,head and body tag

```
  <html class="gr__localhost">
        <head>
        <script src=""></script>
        </head>
        <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true"><menuroot name="main"></menuroot></body></html>
```

I want output as

```
<menuroot name="main"></menuroot>
```

Want remove other html tags

Comment: Can you explaine some details why you want do that? You can use strip tags to delete that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$html = file_get_html('yourHTMLfile.html');
$body = $html->find('body');
```